# How to detect and refresh outdated data in React Native app with redux-persist

Tags: caching, react-native, redux, cache-expiration

In a `React Native` app, using`Redux` and `Redux-Persist`, what is the best way to identify what content needs to be updated?

I have an app that does a few requests at startup.
When I enabled `redux-persist` I started to avoid a request if it was already done at another time. But I have no idea how best to identify whether or not to make the request again to update the data stored by redux-persist.

I read about the use of `ETags` and`Last-Modified`, but this implies implementing this in the API also right?

Any guidance for this functionality implemented in the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you also need to update your API.

Another solution is to use push notifications to notify that the data changed and perform a new request every time the notification is received. But this also means implementing some code on server side.

You need a way to know that the data changed, for that reason you always need to implement some code in server side.

Comment: Understand. But adding push notifications just to identify updates is not something very intrusive for the user?

Comment: You can use silent push notifications. See more about it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1

Comment: Thanks. I will check!